# How to avoid iOS project duplicate symbols link error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, duplicates, linker-errors

I am developing an iOS app using "Brother Print SDK for iPhone iPad".
It can be gotten from [here](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/mobile/ios/download/index.htm#forios).

I drag and drop BRPtouchPrinterKit.framework under my app frameworks folder.
In my app, there is a PrintViewController and I import the header as follows.

PrinterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <BRPtouchPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h>

@interface PrintViewController : UIViewController <BRPtouchNetworkDelegate> {
    BRPtouchNetwork*            ptn;
    BRPtouchNetworkInfo*        pti;
}
```

BRPtouchPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BRPtouchPrinter.h"
#import "BRPtouchNetwork.h"
#import "BRPtouchNetworkInfo.h"
#import "BrPtPJ673_def.h"

@interface BRPtouchPrinterKit : NSObject

@end
```

If I import PrintViewController in my other viewcontrollers, I am always facing duplicate symbol errors.

SettingsViewController.m (not header file)

```
#import "PrintViewController.h"
...
```

link error:

```
    duplicate symbol _printerSeries in: 
    /Users/.../PrintViewController.o
    /Users/.../SettingsViewController.o

    duplicate symbol _rasterGraphicType in: 
    /Users/.../PrintViewController.o
    /Users/.../SettingsViewController.o

    ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

the symbol "_printerSeries" and "_rasterGraphicType" are defined in BRPtouchPrinter.h file.

```
typedef enum {
    DEFAULT_SERIES,
    PT_SERIES,
    QL_SERIES
} PRINTER_SERIES;

typedef enum {
    TYPE_DEFAULT,
    TYPE_G,
    TYPE_g
} RASTER_GRAPHIC_TYPE;
PRINTER_SERIES      printerSeries;
RASTER_GRAPHIC_TYPE rasterGraphicType;
```

Questions:

1. Why this link error is occurred?
2. How can I avoid this?

Comment: That probably happens because you include BRPtouchPrinter somewhere twice  - therefore the symbols are defined twice. What are the other includes of the SettingsViewController, maybe some of them include the BRPtouchPrinter too.

Comment: There is a print feature in the settings screen, so I have to import "PrinterViewController.h" in "SettingsViewController.m".  There is a "#import <BRPtouchPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h>" in the "PrinterViewController.h". Maybe this makes a problem?

Comment: that alone should not be a problem. Does the PrintViewController gets included somewhere else? Any does that including class maybe gets included in the Settings as well?

Comment: Could you please show the imports of the Settings.m and the Settings.h!?

Comment: There are several  imports other viewcontrollers in settings.h & settings.m. But if I commented "import PrintViewController.h", it works well, uncomment the line, then link error.

Comment: the problem is narrowed down. if I "#import <BRPtouchPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h>" in any .h or .m file, the link error is occurred. But not sure why this error comes in.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the declaration of these two global variables `printerSeries` and `rasterGraphicType` in the .h file;  As you see you get a duplicate symbol if you include the .h file in more than one location.

In my opinion this is actually some pretty poor coding on the part of Brother; these variables should be properly encapsulated in some object somewhere, but we can't fix that.

What you *can* do is make these static variables so that there is only a single instance of the symbol and the linker error goes away.

Edit BPRtouchPrinter.h so that it is

```
typedef enum {
    DEFAULT_SERIES,
    PT_SERIES,
    QL_SERIES
} PRINTER_SERIES;

typedef enum {
    TYPE_DEFAULT,
    TYPE_G,
    TYPE_g
} RASTER_GRAPHIC_TYPE;

static PRINTER_SERIES      printerSeries;
static RASTER_GRAPHIC_TYPE rasterGraphicType
```

**NOTE:** My code still seems to work with these changes and they look like they should be shared globals anyway, so the `static` should be OK, but I can't guarantee there won't be some issue.